# JDO Sql last Generated Key (SCOPE_IDENTITY)

Tags: sql-server, jdo, datanucleus

i am using JDO Sql to execute an insert sql statement in an SQL Server database. 
Is there a way to retrieve the latest generated Id? (table does have an identity column)

i tried to execute a SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() query but i always get a NULL return value

Comment: I think MSSQL uses "SELECT @@IDENTITY" to get the most recent IDENTITY value. But then this is nothing to do with JDO. JDO supports IDENTITY value generation using the normal makePersistent api

Comment: I also came to believe that this is not a JDO Sql issue but an sql server issue. the SELECT @@IDENTITY query works fine but i would not risk using it because of concurrency issues.